# Running SQL within same session as my SQLDeveloper debugger

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

This seems an obvious requirement/use-case to me, but I haven't found anything online.

I'm debugging a PL/SQL Stored Proc which stores data in pseudo-temporary tables along the way (they are just regular tables, whose content is wiped at the end of the transaction). I'd like to inspect these values as I go. However, there seems to be no way to run arbitrary SQL within the same session that is debugging the stored proc. If I try select * from temp_..., I get no rows back and I can see that I have more than one connection open to the database.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is a way to do exactly what you asked. How about either a) committing the rows you're working with, querying them from another session during debug, then truncating your table when finished or b) add a default false debug parameter to your stored proc, then output what you wish when it is set true.

Comment: Thanks, I strongly suspect you're right. I've been doing the two things you describe, but was hoping for a way to inspect as I went.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in PL/SQL Developer, called `Session Mode`.

Go to `Tools->Preferences->Connection->Session Mode`, then select `'Single session'`.

When you switch to single session mode your pl/sql procedure and other connections on behalf of one user will reside within single session. So you will be able to execute sql during debug and inspect all the data you want to.

Comment: Is PL/SQL Developer different than Oracle SQL Developer (since this option doesn't seem to exist in Oracle SQL Developer)?

Comment: Yes, those are different software products.